# Implementing passport, getting bad request

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to implement authentication by using passport.js on a node.js application but get a

> bad request

returning when i post to /login.

I have tested the route and it works well but i get this bad request error everytime i plug in passport.authenticate().

What did i miss?

**Here is my code**

### server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bp = require("body-parser");
const User = require("./db").user;
const Investment = require("./db").investment;
const spending = require("./db").spendings;
const reminder = require("./db").reminder;
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

require("./config/passport")(passport);

app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/Public_static"));
app.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bp.json());

//Passport Authentication Implementation
app.use(session({ secret: "keyboard cat", resave: true, saveUninitialized: true })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash());

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        where: { email: req.body.username }
    })
        .then(function(user) {
            console.log(user);
            user._modelOptions.classMethods.test();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});

app.listen(3100, function() {
    console.log("Server started on http://localhost:3100");
});
```

### /config/passport.js

```js
const User = require("../db").user;
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findOne({where:{id:id}})
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
            {
                passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
            },
            (req, username, password, done) => {
                User.findOne({where: { username: username }})
                .then((user)=>{
                    console.log("User found")
                })
                .catch(()=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        )
    );


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing your passport.js file to:

```
const User = require("../db").user;
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const Promise = require("bluebird");

module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) =>
        Promise.try(() => User.findById(id))
            .asCallback(done)
    );

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
            {
                passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
            },
            (req, username, password, done) => {
                User.findOne({where: { username: username }})
                .then(user =>{
                    console.log("User found")
                    return done(null, user, {message: 'User found!'});
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    return done('Unauthorized', false, {message: err.message});
                })
            }
        )
    );


};
```

Comment: I changed it and i still get the same bad request error.

Comment: My bad, i had wrongly configured postman! Thanks for the help @Svetoslav Petrov